# Limit user to access a APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get the user's detail information:

```
class UserDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    """
    User detail information
    """
    queryset = User.objects.filter(is_valid=True).exclude(status=4)
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    lookup_field = "username"
```

I want to limit other users to access this APIView, I want only admin user and the user it self to access that.

How to limit this?

Comment: There's everything you need to know about it within the Django REST framework documentation, in particular the permissions page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define your own permission class.something like this:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class OwnerProfilePermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """object lvl permissions for owner """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

and in your views include `permission_classes` .see DRF documention.
http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/permissions

and the class base views you choose is important.
http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/generic-views

Comment: I want to judge the user in the APIView. Is it possible?

Comment: for create model you can use CreateAPI view.for update use UpdateAPIView .for viewing model RetrieveAPIView.